# How Extract type from union by its field type

Tags: typescript

I want to make `sendCommand` to return value of type which comes from union `InputActions`, and which is selected according to `action_id` type. Here is my code

```js
interface OutputAction1 {
  command: 'start',
  params: string;
}

interface OutputAction2 {
  command: 'end'
  data: string;
}

type OutputActions = OutputAction1 | OutputAction2;

interface InputAction1 {
  action_id: 'start',
  token: string
}

interface InputAction2 {
  action_id: 'end',
  userData: string
}


type InputActions = InputAction1 | InputAction2;

const sendCommand = (action: OutputActions): Extract<InputActions, {action_id: OutputActions['command']}> => {
    return action.command === 'start' ? {
      action_id: 'start',
      token: '123'
    }:{
    action_id: 'end',
    userData: '123'
    }
 
}

let k = sendCommand({command: 'start', params: ''})
k.token // Property 'token' does not exist on type 'InputAction2'
```

I want `k` to be of type `InputAction1` but its type is `InputActions`. Is there way to tell TS that it should be of type which is selected by `action_id` type which comes from args?

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIFcwAdMEEFjAD2IAjMgN4CwAUMsgkQLZNwgAmAXMgOQDOYOFDA8ANLXpYhcJn24CooAOYBuWgF9atUJFiIUGbHgLEQAJkoSGzVh248IHHlfZxB8sIpCqNWmmABPLANMHDB8QhI%20ZABeNFDjSLJkAB94o3CTEjM1Gm1waHgkZABJEDCI03JqOmREJIB9YC5eASERcVqwIgBrRw8vJV88mh1C-VLyxNMLGvp60yaWhydO%20nQ%20aAARNzgB5WG-QODJiqyQaLiys6TyNOvp7NzaRguwZE2OAGEbNnZY5AACgWJG4hhupj4AEpuABRAAennqAB4HpkknxRJQQSAlmCEujIQBtHiMFh-HgAXXUAD5YnS5vRkFAIGB0FAQHVzgA6Mm2f4xQWtQTCHjIAD8llqTK5jWa9jaorWMuQ3T6IHspDMAGZnNLkOpOIz5uc8bxHOwxFZ1psoDt3LwtbrrQaJIcaAAbVnIHoAz7sH7kjiAih8v4KkUdZBSKAyOS8HjqKG0HrctWOZAAekzyAAClAiMFhAFeOmQGL2EQINEQER3hB4cABMgSKqgigeGjKtkeEA)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with [Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) here and not overcomplicate things. The return type will be inferred correctly automatically.

```
function sendCommand(action: OutputAction1): InputAction1;
function sendCommand(action: OutputAction2): InputAction2;
function sendCommand(action: OutputActions) {
  return action.command === "start"
    ? {
        action_id: "start",
        token: "123"
      }
    : {
        action_id: "end",
        userData: "123"
      };
}

let k = sendCommand({command: "start", params: ""});
// let k: InputAction1

let k2 = sendCommand({command: "end", data: ""});
// let k2: InputAction2
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIFcwAdMEEFjAD2IAjMgN4CwAUMsgkQLZNwgAmAXMgEQDOYOFDA8A3LXpYhcJn24CooAObiaAX1q1QkWIhQZseAsRAAmShIbNWHbjwgcxl9nEHywikCtoaatMACeWPqYOGD4hCR8yAC8aKFGkWTIAD7xhuHGJKaqWuDQ8EjIAJIgYREm5NR0yIhJAPrAXLwCQiKq9GBEANYO7p7e6po02gV6JWWJJubV9HUmjc32jh3I6HzQACKucP3Kqr7+QSil5Vkg0XGnUyTkadeZSTnDMOgg58gbHADC1mzsAAp5iRuAYzklSABKbgPCq3VSvd5JT4Odi-Fj-IHnUEJR7TaETcHTBFvD5fNF-DhYpI4jJwi6Qiw1KAQMDoKAgWrnAB0jAxHFiMTi-EEwh4lnoAH4mfRZbLgSBFnZWmKADQSuXILq9EB2UimADM4pqct8cu4s01c3OSt4qJ46pNmvWWx2esNxqtagOwwANqzkN1YiifpTARQ+TYliqRKrkFIoDI5LweGpIaoAPQZ5D+sCBmGTPG3P0B7rmOLk9FRgERsN2e1xlxuFNpzPZ3OB0wFonZIADhYpI4jJwi6Qiw1Wb0ZBQCBgdBQEC1c4AOkYGI4sRicX4gmEPEsrOQAH4mTLFbyGk07K1JQAaaVK5BdXogOykUwAZilNSVviV3BZOuVC1VvFRPC15p16y2O0NJrNtrUq18hxoABsOchurEUT9KYCKIKbEt1SINcgpFAZHJeDw1JDVAB6XPIENgMMwyZ427DIth8xxcno%20MA2PRuxO5MuNyZ7N5gtV7qmUtE7JAA)